# Connect to MS SQL Server 2014 from a computer on a different network

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have created an Application in VB.NET with database in MSSQL 2014.

I have configured TCP/IP=1433, UDP=1434, Windows Firewall is configured to allow 1433, 1434, sqlserver.exe, sqlbrowser.exe and server's login settings are configured. Application is working on my laptop which is on the same Internet connection as the host computer. I am trying to use the Application on client computer which is on another network and getting NAMED PIPES PROVIDER error40.

This is connection I am using:

```
Data Source=myServerName;InitialCatalog=dbName;UserId=clientcomputerName;Password=x
```

Do I need to configure client's computer in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Does your DNS/HOSTS file resolve the remote computer name? Try IP address instead if not. Not sure but not all versions of SQL support remote connections via Named Pipes (can sometimes get round this by using registry hacks to add the connection as ODBC)

Comment: I will try with IP address and see what happens. Will keep updating this thread

Comment: No avail with IP address